If statement to determine box on form is empty
I have an Access database and from the form I want an email to trigger if the DaysLeft box is less than 5 and the MoveOutPacket box is empty.
I have this code but it is not emailing.
Private Sub DaysLeft_Change()

If (DaysLeft < 5) And (MoveOutPacket = Null) Then
    Dim Msg As String
    Msg = "Maintenance Team, we will recieve the keys for " & Property & " on " & Recieved_Keys & " please schedule cleaning and carpet cleaning if the unit is vacant."

    Dim O As Outlook.Application
    Dim M As Outlook.MailItem
    Set O = New Outlook.Application
    Set M = O.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With M
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .HTMLBody = Msg
        .To = "hannah@208.properties"
        .Send
    End With

    Set M = Nothing
    Set O = Nothing

End If
End Sub


Do you mean the DaysLeft is a textbox? If so then if would be If (DaysLeft.Text < 5) And (MoveOutPacket.Text = "") Then

@JeremyThompson, Value is default property for data controls in Access VBA, not Text. I don't allow empty strings in fields and my textbox would be null. Cannot compare anything to Null. Use IsNull(): If DaysLeft < 5 And IsNull(MoveOutPacket) Then.

Why visio tag selected?

Is user inputting value in DaysLeft? This is not a calculation?

Null is an unknown value, and you can't compare unknown values for equality. Use IsNull() instead. This is true in almost all database management systems (with the exception of MySQL and Oracle, to mention two).

Please read: Debugging VBA Code . This is essential to find out what your code is actually doing.

In VBA, cannot compare anything to Null, not even Null.
Use IsNull() function: If DaysLeft < 5 And IsNull(MoveOutPacket) Then
Might also want to correct spelling: receive.
